# Parsing a table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the table from https://alreits.com/screener

I have tried this:

```
main_url = 'https://alreits.com/screener'
r = requests.get(main_url)
df_list = pd.read_html(r.text)
df = df_list[0]
print(df)
```

but pandas cant find the table.
I have also tried using BeautifulSoup4 but it didnt seem to give better results.
This is the selector: #__next > div.MuiContainer-root.MuiContainer-maxWidthLg > div.MuiBox-root.jss9.Card__CardContainer-feksr6-0.fpbzHQ.ScreenerTable__CardContainer-sc-1c5wxgl-0.GRrTj > div > table > tbody

This is the full xPath: /html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody

I am trying to get the Stock symbol (under name),sector,score and market cap. The other data would be nice to have but is not necessary.

Thank You!

Comment: You can't use `requests / bs4`, you have to use `Selenium` because data are loaded with a call to an [API](https://api.alreits.com:8080/api/reits/screener?page=0&size=500&sort=marketCap,desc&sort=score,desc&sort=ffoGrowth,desc). Or fake session, user-agent and call directly the api with `requests`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one JSON url from the dev tool. This is an easy way to extract the table instead of using selenium. Use post request to extract the data.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.alreits.com:8080',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'origin': 'https://alreits.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://alreits.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('page', '0'),
    ('size', '500'),
    ('sort', ['marketCap,desc', 'score,desc', 'ffoGrowth,desc']),
)

data = '{"filters":[]}'

response = requests.post('https://api.alreits.com:8080/api/reits/screener', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

df = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The code below will return the data you are looking for.

```
import requests
import pprint
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.post(
    'https://api.alreits.com:8080/api/reits/screener?page=0&size=500&sort=marketCap,desc&sort=score,desc&sort=ffoGrowth,desc',
    headers=headers, data=json.dumps({'filters':[]}))
if r.status_code == 200:
    pprint.pprint(r.json())
    # Now you have the data - do what you want with it
else:
    print(r.status_code)
```